# Linux: List Unknown defconfig Items At Build Time

Tags: linux, config, yocto

Is there a way to get a list of all unknown config items in a defconfig for a custom Linux kernel?

The specific use case is supporting a long-overdue BSP update in which the vendor changed a bunch of config item names without notice or documentation.  Perhaps this can be done via some sort of `sort` + `diff` magic, though I am unsure which of the generated files to compare against?  Or is this best compared against `/proc/config.gz` extracted from a running host?

---

Edit: "Unknown config" in this case refers to `CONFIG_*` defines which don't have a matching entry in a `Kconfig` somewhere.  For example, the vendor in question changed the `Makefile` for one of their drivers to build based off of `CONFIG_PINCTRL_S32CC` (was `CONFIG_PINCTRL_S32GEN1`).  My defconfig specified the previous name (`*_S32GEN1`) which is now undefined (should be `*_S32CC`).

These platform-specific name changes are easy to identify however there are others which are less obvious.  My goal is to list all of the unknown entries in my defconfig so I can evaluate each in turn and correct as appropriate.

---

**Mods:** Not sure if this belongs on U&L; I am asking here since the question involves *building* the Linux kernel rather than *using* it.

Comment: Explain more about "unkown config", you need to know if the client changed something in th configuration ?

Comment: Updated in the original question.